# How to passively prevent Windows from blanking screen on a locked down Win10?

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, blank-screen

I have a computer with Windows 10, and I want to make the time until screen goes blank longer than 15 minutes.

Things I've tried:

- Changing the time under screensaver. Worked when setting it lower than 15 minutes, but not higher.
- Changing power settings. Same deal here. Worked for less than 15 minutes but not more.
- [Simulating input with script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56636565/6699433) Didn't work because running scripts is disabled.

It's a pretty locked down computer. I cannot install programs and such, except for those approved by the company. I'm using that computer pretty passively, but I want to have it open to see if anyone in my team has written something in Teams. Constantly moving the mouse to prevent it is tedious and breaks concentration.

So is there a way to prevent the screen from going blank?

Comment: Perhaps playing a video could help, minimized and muted of course. Maybe even in a browser.

Comment: Most likely your admins have configured a group policy that sets the screen saver time out to 15 minutes. There is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Most media players inform Windows that it should stay awake and the screen should stay active. (This is done using [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) or [`PowerSetRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-powersetrequest) and friends.) After all, you wouldn’t want the screen saver to activate while a movie is playing. Nowadays, browsers are media players, too!

So you can try running a movie, preferably endlessly looped, in one of the media players you have available. If the player is “reasonably dumb”, it should also work when minimized and muted.

Keep in mind that Windows may override the application requests if on battery power.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielB's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1697154/707055) works. I'd like to add a few things about that.

Playing a youtube video in Edge (which I have to use) works, but there are some limitations. It does not work if I change tab, and I cannot have the window minimized. The window does not need to be focused, but it have to be at least partially visible, so you cannot have a maximized window on top of it.

There is one youtube video that is recommended for this, and that's [10 hours of nothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tOlh-g2dxrI)

If you prefer to use a standalone video player, I can recommend learning [how to generate a 2hour-long blank video](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11453082/6699433), but I have not tried this approach myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PowerPoint installed, put any presentation in "Slide Show" or Presentation Mode.  It typically prevents the screensaver from turning on.